# C#: projection - accessing a given string property in a collection of objects in the same way as a List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, collections, projection

a quick projection question.  I have a collection of objects (unchangeditems) in a test method, and would like to ensure they match my 'expected' elements.  As shown you could do it by element, but this isn't ideal.  I'm sure its possible to use projection to get down to the string variable (LMAA_CODE - don't ask about the capitals!) along the lines of the bottom line below.  I'd appreciate a hand.

Thanks!

```
// Works but not very elegant
            Assert.AreEqual(result.unchangedItems[0].LMAA_CODE,expectedunchangedItems[0]);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.unchangedItems[1].LMAA_CODE,expectedunchangedItems[1]);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.unchangedItems[2].LMAA_CODE,expectedunchangedItems[2]);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.unchangedItems[3].LMAA_CODE,expectedunchangedItems[3]);

        // ?Can something like this be done?  eg result.unchangedItems => result.unchangedItems.LMAA_CODE
        Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(result.unchangedItems.LMAA_CODE, expectedunchangedItems));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there already, just added a projection to LMAA_CODE:

```
 Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(result.unchangedItems.Select( x=> x.LMAA_CODE), 
                                        expectedunchangedItems));
```

Comment: Yep, this was exactly what I had in my minds eye.  Thanks for the effort BrokenGlass!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.unchangedItems.Count; i++) {
    Assert.AreEqual(result.unchangedItems[i].LMAA_CODE, expectedUnchangedItems[i]);
}
```

You can also do:

```
Assert.IsFalse(result.unchangedItems.Where((r,i) => expectedUnchangedItems[i] != r.LMAA_CODE).Any())
```

`.Any()` will return *true* if the filtered sequence contains elements, and it shouldn't. That's why you call `IsFalse`. If your testing framework (or whatever you are using) does not have that, you can always do `Assert.AreEqual(____, false)`.

Comment: `x.Where(...).Any() ==> x.Any(...)` **Edit**: doh. :\

Comment: @Porges I don't think `Any()` has the overload that accepts the index position `:)`

Comment: The loop idea was my first impulse but I knew I was 'a projection away'.  BrokenGlass's idea was what I was trying to get to.  Thanks for the comment mate!

Comment: @Glinkot You're welcome. I still would use the loop, so I can know exactly where it fails. Do not try to compact everything :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and `Zip`:

```
Assert.IsTrue(result.unchangedItems.Zip(expectedunchangedItems, (actual, expected) => actual.LMAA_CODE == expected).All(value => value));
```

Comment: I'd never heard of the zip command, just looked it up, very interesting.  Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a "Zip" extension method.

```
Assert.AreEqual(result.unchangedItems.Count, expectedunchangedItems.Count);
result.unchangedItems.Zip(expectedunchangedItems, (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b))
                     .ForEach(p => Assert.AreEqual(p.Item1.LMAA_CODE, p.Item2));
```

This way, the exception reports which value was not expected. The Zip() method is included in .NET 4, but I personally prefer to use my own, and of course you'd want a ForEach() too:

```
// I actually have a Pair<A,B> struct that I prefer to use, but 
// KeyValuePair or Tuple works almost as well.
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<A, B>> ZipTuples<A, B>(this IEnumerable<A> a, IEnumerable<B> b)
{
    IEnumerator<A> ea = a.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<B> eb = b.GetEnumerator();
    while (ea.MoveNext() && eb.MoveNext())
        yield return new Tuple<A, B>(ea.Current, eb.Current);
}
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in list)
        action(item);
}
```

Usage:

```
Assert.AreEqual(result.unchangedItems.Count, expectedunchangedItems.Count);
result.unchangedItems.ZipTuples(expectedunchangedItems)
                     .ForEach(p => Assert.AreEqual(p.Item1.LMAA_CODE, p.Item2));
```